# More specific feedback for why my question has remained closed

Tags: discussion, specific-question, reopen-request, closed-questions, close-reasons

I asked [a question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/170867/got-rejected-in-a-coding-interview-even-though-i-felt-i-could-get-to-the-next-ro) some time ago and it got closed. Apparently, the question was not focused enough so I edited the question yesterday and raised a flag to have it reopened. I see that the number of my flags has gone back from 9 to 10 so I guess the moderators decided against reopening my question. No comments were given for why my request was rejected. I want this question to be reopened so I would appreciate it if I can get **more specific feedback** for the current form of my question.

Comment: To me it just reads like your main question is about how to ace a very particular type of technical test that is simply not within this site's scope. If you focused more on timed tests in general, whether you're drawing the right conclusion (I think you might not be) or even just which lessons you can draw from this to improve, that would be more within our scope. It's not unlike posting a question on how to ace your first day as a sous-chef in a professional kitchen. That's also a question about work but it's about that particular job, not the concept of workplaces more generally.

Comment: @Lilienthal _To me it just reads like your main question is about how to ace a very particular type of technical test that is simply not within this site's scope._ We can use a tag called `software-industry` and the tag's description stated it corresponds to questions specific to the software industry. Due to the presence of this tag, I figured it is acceptable to ask my question here.

Comment: Understandable, but industry-specific tags mostly exist for questions on navigating the industry.We have a [tag:startup] tag as well yet don't allow the sort of questions that the now deleted Startups site covered. And while we might touch on security topics we don't cover anywhere near the scope of [security.se]. As mentioned versions of this question would be on-topic but if you're specifically after technical answers to improve your skills in this area, this isn't the best place compared to something like [programmers.se]. Though I'm not sure if they accept a question like this.

Comment: @Lilienthal I am going to flag the question again to get the moderators' attention.

Comment: There's really no point in doing so. Moderator flags shouldn't be used to get questions reopened, meta posts like this one are. We'd decline a flag like that. Your question has 2 reopen votes at present but it's likely that not enough support exists for it to be reopened even after the edits you made.

Answer (score 5):

I can't speak for the people who have closed the question, but I'd hazard a guess that the people latched onto the coding issue itself instead of looking at the workplace issue. We've seen in the past that supplying coding or technical examples often leads to discussions around those technical aspects of the question rather than addressing the interview/rejection aspect (which is more on-topic for this SE site).

Removing the code snippet and generalising the issue ("I was given a coding exercise and couldn't solve it in time, but did after the interview") may have resulted in more focussed answers and comments and protection from closure.

Comment: Thank you. This is the type of actionable suggestions I wanted.

Answer (score 3):

It was closed by the community. I see no reason to reopen it as it hasn't substantially changed. It has 9 answers already, none of which suited you. If it didn't have the answers I might be more inclined.

The community can reopen it if they wish. This is the right place to ask for that to happen.

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for the response. The question received many excellent answers. This is why I decided not to select a best answer.

Comment: Moreover, the reason for closing is not helpful for me. It would have been more helpful for me if the given reason was more specific to my question.

Comment: That's fine, if enough people agree it will be reopened. Or they may give you some more specific feedback here.